# 'else without rescue is useless' and 'require' juggernaut/ruby problems on Mac 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, comet, juggernaut

```
1. Install Ruby on Rails

sudo gem install rails
2. Install the Juggernaut Gem

sudo gem install juggernaut
3. Download the demo app and unpack it.

4. Start the Rails application

ruby script/server
5. Start the Juggernaut server

juggernaut -c juggernaut.yml
6. Open the browser and go to http://localhost:3000
```

I have attempted all morning to follow these very simple instructions but my computer seems so have problems with every single juggernaut application. I installed ruby, installed juggernaut and git cloned the application from github. Then I cd'd the directory and attempted `rails s`. I got

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

I then tried `juggernaut -c juggernaut.yml` and got

```
/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:128: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require': /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:122: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
        when :broadcast: broadcast_command
                        ^
/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:363: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut.rb:157:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/bin/juggernaut:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/juggernaut:19:in `load'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/juggernaut:19:in `<main>'
```

Can someone PLEASE help me. Any non-juggernaut rails app works fine on my computer by the way.

Comment: I know you're upset.. but maybe you should change the title to something more relevant for your problem

Comment: Sorry, I changed the title, but do you know how to fix these problems?

Comment: 'else without rescue is useless' ? Maybe take another stab at the title?

Comment: I'd wish I could help you but unfortunatelly I don't know how to answer your question. Other than that, I can tell you for sure that asking the question with the right title increases your chances for the right person (who knows the answer) to check out your question and answer it. The question is well formatted and that's why I'll give you a +1 for that. If  your question is not answered in 7 days you can also start a bounty on it.. and that will draw even more attention. Good Luck!

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Could you provide the URL for downloading the demo app you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Have you tried a different ruby version? Looks like a ruby 1.8 / 1.9 compatibility issue is causing juggernaut grief.

Comment: Also..

From the backtrace you've provided it looks like you're using the old version of juggernaut. Take a look at https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut for the latest and greatest. I'm pretty sure this version is 1.9.2 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems on centos. This could happen if the gem setup is incorrect (don't know what but something to do with sudo)

try running it within a bundler 
`bundle exec rails s`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error `'warning: else without rescue is useless'` with something completely different.

Its a strange one, but once I saw how you can generate the error, I found the problem and fixed it.

http://nofail.de/2011/12/ruby-quirks/

Basically somewhere in the Gem or in the code you added, you have a malformed `if` statement.

Strangely this error was not causing issues except for one developer. This malformed `if` made it to production and appears to be working. On his development box it would flag the error and then do ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION and die.